# Restful Web Service Error Handling

Tags: python, exception, flask, sqlalchemy

In my `API`, when creating a new user, I call a number of functions:

```
userInfo = request.get_json()           
email = userInfo.get('email')       
password = userInfo.get('password')
validate_email(email)       
validate_password(password)     

if (no_errors):
    add_user_to_database(user)
else:
    return exception(?)
```

My goal is that I want to collect any and all errors that arise from the result of any of the first 3 `function` calls. It is possible that one function may catch more than one error.

Eg:

```
def validate_email(email):
    if email is None:
        # store error
    else:
        if email_already_on_server(email)
           # store error
        if email_too_long(email)
           # store error

    # What should I be doing here..
```

After I have all my `errors` stored, I want to return an `exception(?)` displaying all the `errors` that were picked up.

I'm not sure what the best way to do this is..

1) Should I create a single object (a custom error class) to pass to all my functions to store any `errors`?

2) If errors are found, what should I return to the user? Would it be a custom `exception`, with a `HTTP status code` also containing all the errors in a `JSON` format?

I'm having a tough time getting my head around the proper way to do this.

Comment: I tend to use custom error class that inherits Exception to store all the collected errors, your validation call can catch this error, read the list of errors and return json as @lapinkoira mentions.

Answer (score 0):

With flask I like to use the jsonify library, then I format the errors in this way:

```
from flask import jsonify

def jsonifys(status_code=200, **kwargs):
    response = jsonify(**kwargs)
    response.status_code = status_code
    return response
```

Then I will raise errors from my methods and in my responses I will return the result like this:

```
return jsonifys(500, error='unable to create process')
```

So any frontend can easly read the error code and the message can provide any info desired. The JSON format also is handy.